# How can i use multipartFormData in Swift / Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

```
upload(.POST, isEdit == true ? mainURL+URLS.UpdateLicense.rawValue : mainURL+URLS.AddLicense.rawValue, multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in

 if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.selectdImage, 1) {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name:   "image", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

I want to append body part in the string and I can't find any method by that I can append a string with this body part. It's required only data.But my parameter is a string and I have to pass it as a string not in data.

Comment: Thanks sahil for editing my code

Comment: @SohilR.Memon  i want to append string parameter with this multipart data.

Comment: Post your paramaters which you want to pass.

Comment: parameter = ["data":[
                    "vehicle_id": vehicalData!.vehicleId,
                    "puc_expire_date":dateStr,
                    "puc_serial_number":txtLicenceNo.text!]
                ]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Swift 2.0**

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: "image")
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
 multipartFormData.append(imageData(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "image")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in my project. I Hope it can help you

```
var parameters: [String: String] = [
        "Tag" : tagName,
        "Title" : title,
        "Content" : content,
        "TypePost" : "0",
        "CreatedAt" : "\(Date())"
    ]

for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to upload `UIImage` with other parameters, so here how you can achieve that!

```
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
}

for (key, value) in parameters {
     multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
}
```

You need to differentiate both the things `UIImage` and other `String` parameters.

Let me know, if you still face problem.